# Merge two dataframes with duplicate

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames which look like and I want to merge them based on the countries

df1:

```
+-------------------+-------------------+--------------+----------+----------+
| Country/Region    | ObservationDate   |  Confirmed   |  Deaths  | Recovered|
+-------------------+-------------------+--------------+----------+----------+
|  Mainland China   |  2020-01-22       |    547       |   17     |  28      | 
|  Indonesia        |  2020-01-22       |    0         |   0      |  0       |
|  Japan            |  2020-01-22       |    2         |   0      |  0       |     
|  Thailand         |  2020-01-22       |    2         |   0      |  0       |    
|  Mainland China   |  2020-01-23       |    639       |   18     |  30      |  
+-----------------+---------------------+--------------+----------+----------+
```

df2:

```
+-----------------+-------------------+--------------------+
| Country         |  Region           |  Tropic/Nontropic  |
+-----------------+-------------------+--------------------+
|  Mainland China |  Asia & Pacific   | nontropic          |
|  Indonesia      |  Asia & Pacific   | tropic             |
|  Japan          |  Asia & Pacific   | nontropic          |
|  Thailand       |  Asia & Pacific   | tropic             | 
+-----------------+-------------------+--------------------+
```

The output I want may look like this:

df__new:

```
+-------------------+-------------------+--------------+----------+----------+-------------------+--------------------+
| Country/Region    | ObservationDate   |  Confirmed   |  Deaths  | Recovered|  Region           |  Tropic/Nontropic  |
+-------------------+-------------------+--------------+----------+----------+-------------------+--------------------+
|  Mainland China   |  2020-01-22       |    547       |   17     |  28      |  Asia & Pacific   | nontropic          | 
|  Indonesia        |  2020-01-22       |    0         |   0      |  0       |  Asia & Pacific   | tropic             |
|  Japan            |  2020-01-22       |    2         |   0      |  0       |  Asia & Pacific   | nontropic          |     
|  Thailand         |  2020-01-22       |    2         |   0      |  0       |  Asia & Pacific   | tropic             |    
|  Mainland China   |  2020-01-23       |    639       |   18     |  30      |  Asia & Pacific   | nontropic          |  
+-----------------+---------------------+--------------+----------+----------+-------------------+--------------------+
```

I have tried:

```py
pd.merge(df_new, df_cat, on=['Country/Region', 'Country'], how='left')
```

But it raised an error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-eff12d512209> in <module>
----> 1 pd.merge(df_new, df_cat, on=['Country/Region', 'Country'], how='left')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in merge(left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
     84         copy=copy,
     85         indicator=indicator,
---> 86         validate=validate,
     87     )
     88     return op.get_result()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in __init__(self, left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, axis, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
    625             self.right_join_keys,
    626             self.join_names,
--> 627         ) = self._get_merge_keys()
    628 
    629         # validate the merge keys dtypes. We may need to coerce

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in _get_merge_keys(self)
    981                     if not is_rkey(rk):
    982                         if rk is not None:
--> 983                             right_keys.append(right._get_label_or_level_values(rk))
    984                         else:
    985                             # work-around for merge_asof(right_index=True)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _get_label_or_level_values(self, key, axis)
   1690             values = self.axes[axis].get_level_values(key)._values
   1691         else:
-> 1692             raise KeyError(key)
   1693 
   1694         # Check for duplicates

KeyError: 'Country/Region'
```

How can I achieve the result on df_new?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the columns you want to compare have different names, therefore you cannot just write `on=['Country/Region', 'Country']` but have to specify the column name in each dataframe.

The error message `KeyError: 'Country/Region'` points that it searches for column that does not exist in one of the tables.

Try -

```
pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, left_on='Country/Region', right_on='Country', how='left')
```

Check documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)